# How to get permission so my app runs in background even in Ultra power saving mode

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using the permissions of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"\>\</uses-permission\>
```

but the app is still not working in background in ultra power saving mode.
It is a simple hello world app which is created just for testing.
This is my code :

```
package com.example.permissiontesting;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Context context=MainActivity.this;
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
        else {
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I am trying different solution but not working

Comment: "the app is still not working in background" -- there is nothing in that code that is doing anything in the background.

Comment: what should I add to check its functionality?